# inarray with duplicate array items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to find the next array item from an array :

```
var srcKpi=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
var value=2;
var nextitem = srcKpi[($.inArray(value, srcKpi) + 1) % srcKpi.length];
console.log(nextitem) // 3
```

It works fine when there are no duplicate items in an array. When i try with duplicate items in an array, i am getting first occurrence element only but not the actual one. I want to get the next array item of the particular value.

```
var srcKpi=[1,2,3,1,5,6];
var value=1;
var nextitem = srcKpi[($.inArray(value, srcKpi) + 1) % srcKpi.length];
console.log(nextitem) // 2
```

When i put this in a loop to get the next value, every time i get `2`only . 
I never get value '5'. 
Any suggestions what i am doing wrong to get next element of the particular element when there are duplicate items are there in an Array ?
For more info :  jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4LCMs/

Comment: `inArray()` supports a third argument for specifying `fromIndex` - which is what you need in this case. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: What is the expected output in the second example?

Comment: So the output should be `[2,5]`? Why don't you just loop an compare?

Comment: please find jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/4LCMs/

Answer (score 0):

You can implement  array `prototype` here.

```
Array.prototype.current = 0;

var Current = Array.prototype.current;
Array.prototype.next = function() {
    if (!((this.current + 1) in this)) return false;
    return this[++this.current];
};
Array.prototype.prev = function() {
    return this[--this.current];
};

var srcKpi=[1,2,3,1,5,6];
for(Current ===0;Current<srcKpi.length;Current++)
console.log(srcKpi.next());
```

Now every Array will have the methods prev and next, and the current property, which points to the "current" elements. A caveat: the current property can be modified, thus leading to non predictable results.

This is what you will get as result :

```
2 
3
1 
5 
6 
false
```

See the working solution here :

http://jsbin.com/ebocoz/1/edit

Remember to `run with js` and see the solution in browser console .

If you want , you can find out `prev` elements as well .

Comment: *"This needs an implementation of array prototype"* No, you don't *need* it. As already pointed out by techfoobar, simply passing a third argument to `$.inArray` would work as well.

Comment: @FelixKling : Probably my wording was wrong, i will change it. But I am more of a fan of `proto` handling. Hence my answer .

Comment: WTH is that `Current` variable supposed to do?

Comment: `current ` gives the current index of the array and `Current` is used to loop through the array until the last element is reached.